# Can I share internet connection with my access point?

Tags: internet, network-shares, wireless-access-point

I have internet connection from isp that use mikrotik. So if want to connect to internet I must to login to mikrotik login page. My problem is isp is limiting the login. So if I want my phones, tablet, etc, I must disconnect my laptop first.

The question is, can I share this connection within the access point. So my access point is do login and get dhcp address automatically. Then share the internet to all my devices. And I am not must login again. Because the access point have do that.

My access point is TP-Link TL-MR3020.

Comment: Hello, it looks like you are trying to share connection in home environnement, which belongs to sister sites like superuser

Answer (score 1):

Funny Internet you have. I mean, my ISP also provides me with Internet via Mikrotik hardare, buti n my case it Ends as a Ethernet cable from the uplink he installed. It is in your case more like you have a Wireless Login...

> can I share this connection within the access point. My access point
>   is TP-Link TL-MR3020

RTFM. If the Access Points can do this, it will lbe in the Manual.

MOST LIKELY though - you have to acutally learn how Networks operate and install a router (mikrotik has nice cheap ones) that acts as the "ISP SIDE" one Computer, and then internally distributs IP addresses and uses NAT to route all the traffic out.

A cheap MIkrotik of the 750 series can do that.

According to the Review a http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/wireless-routers/1290157/tp-link-tl-mr3020

for your device:

> The TP-Link MR3020 is a compact 3G router that lets you share your
>   wireless 3G dongle with more than one Wi-Fi-enabled device

This really is a Point for you to pull out the documentation and read it.

Voting to Close- this i - btw. - off Topic on ServerFault as this is not "in a professional capacity". Home Networks fall into Superuser.